# how to override the ice:commandLink css

Tags: java, css, jsf, icefaces

I user the icefaces commandLink in my application and i want to add an icone in watermark. I add an attribute styleCss="disconnect" in the commandLink, but it's never considered during the rendering. when i get the html code generated the style applied is the defautl style : iceCmdLnk

in my XHTML file i have :

```
<ice:commandLink value="Disconnect" styleCss="disconnect"
                            rendered="#{myBean.authentified}"
                            action="#{navigationBean.disconnect}" />
```

html code generated :

```
<a onfocus="setFocus(this.id);" onclick="var form=formOf(this);form['headerForm:j_idcl'].value='headerForm:j_idt16';iceSubmit(form,this,event);form['headerForm:j_idcl'].value='';return false;" onblur="setFocus('');" id="headerForm:j_idt16" href="javascript:;" class="iceCmdLnk">Disconnect</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution ... I think I forgot to remove my gloves before starting code ... I put styleCss instead of styleClass ...